# use package {apacite} with Frontiers in Psychology template

Tags: apacite

I want to use the APA style format for References in a Frontiers in Psychology paper. Unfortunately, when I try to use the `apacite` package i receive multiple error messages. How do can I best implement the APA style format for my References list in combination with the Frontiers template?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What are the error messages you're getting? It would be helpful if you provided a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) that reproduces the problem and that others can compile to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the `apacite` package on top of `frontiersSCNS`. Download the kit from
https://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers_LaTeX_Templates.zip.

Compile `frontiers.tex`  + bibtex + compile twice and the references will appear in your document.

The sample .bib file included is `test.bib`.

For Science, Engineering and Humanities and Social Sciences articles use
`\bibliographystyle{frontiersinSCNS_ENG_HUMS}`  as style.

Use `\citep{<xx>}` for in-text citations, as in

```
For Original Research Articles \citep{conference}, Clinical Trial Articles \citep{article},
and Technology Reports \citep{patent}, 
the introduction should be succinct, with no subheadings \citep{book}. 
For Case Reports the Introduction should
include symptoms at presentation \citep{chapter},
physical exams and lab results \citep{dataset}.
```

[image: A]